# Cant connect to SSH server (Ubuntu) from home wifi

Tags: 14.04, ssh, error-handling, openssh

My SSH server set up at my workspace usually from a mobile SSH application with cellural data i can reach ssh anywhere,but when i'm home and i want to do my thing it just wont connecting. The server far away so it is not my server and my wifi do not use specific settings. And also i've configured the SSH myself.

Comment: Are you saying that you CAN connect to your work ssh server from your phone anywhere, but you CANNOT connect to your work ssh server from your home desktop/laptop?

Comment: @user535733 yes

Comment: Show us your terminal session: Your ssh command followed by the complete output showing failure to connect. Use ssh's `-v` flag to include debugging information. .